# Pandas read_html skips header of table (python)

Tags: python, html, xml, pandas

Everything with class `rowheader` or `data` is importing to pandas using `read_html`, but the lines with class `header` are not.

So essentially, I'm getting all the data, but not the column labels that tell me what the data actually is.

How can I fix that?

```html
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

<head>
  <meta name="Generator" content="SAS Software Version 9.3, see www.sas.com">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <colgroup>
      <col>
        <col>
          <col>
            <col>
    </colgroup>
    <colgroup>
      <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2" colspan="4" scope="colgroup">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="header" colspan="2" scope="colgroup">SubDistrict</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header" scope="col">Title1
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td class="header" scope="col">Title2
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rowheader" rowspan="12" scope="rowgroup">M1</td>
        <td class="rowheader" scope="row">1.1</td>
        <td class="rowheader" scope="row">var1</td>
        <td class="rowheader" scope="row">TOTAL</td>
        <td class="data">7</td>
        <td class="data">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        etc...
```

Comment: Can you share the script you used?